# Adding and merging elements of list of lists comparing other two lists if match found on the same position

Tags: python, list, filter, merge

So I have three lists of same length.

```
a = [[24, 24, 24, 24], [24, 24, 24, 24], [24, 24, 24, 24], [7, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [17, 7, 0, 0], [6, 1, 0, 0], [0, 17, 7, 0], [0, 6, 1, 0], [0, 0, 17, 0], [0, 0, 6, 1], [0, 0, 2, 5], [0, 0, 0, 6], [0, 0, 0, 4]]

users = ['Khod OR', 'Zader', 'Kamel Tor', 'Dave', 'Samir Fein', 'Chris', 'Samir Fein', 'Dave', 'Samir Fein', 'Chris', 'Samir Fein', 'Chris', 'Samir Fein', 'Dave']

schedules = ['ItSupport', 'NetworkOps', 'InfraDevOps', 'DBOps', 'SecOps', 'DBOps', 'SecOps', 'DBOps', 'SecOps', 'DBOps', 'SecOps', 'DBOps', 'SecOps', 'DBOps']
```

I want to compare the `list users` with `list schedules` first; if there are multiple users with same name in `users` list I will check corresponding schedule in `schedules` list, if schedules are also same on same position; I want to add up the elements on same position in `list a` and merge the same.

e.g user `Chris` is found on index 5,9 & 11 and corresponding schedule on 5,9 & 11 position is also same i.e. `DBOps` so I will get the elements of same position in `list a` which are `[17, 7, 0, 0]` , `[0, 0, 17, 0]` & `[0, 0, 2, 5]` so I will merge these 3 elements (lists) into one by adding the corresponding values on same position to produce single element [17,7,19,5].

So my output will be three new lists

```
a = [[24,24,24,24],[24,24,24,24],[24,24,24,24],[7,17,7,4],[7,7,7,7],[17,7,19,5]]

users = ['Khod OR', 'Zader', 'Kamel Tor', 'Dave', 'Samir Fein', 'Chris']

schedules = ['ItSupport', 'NetworkOps', 'InfraDevOps', 'DBOps','SecOps','DBOps']
```

Comment: What if the users and schedules *don't* match?  It looks like they all match in this example, but the way you describe the problem it sounds like that's not a guarantee.

Comment: @Samwise Those should be untouched.

Comment: What does "untouched" mean?  If there is a user with multiple schedules, they should be completely absent from the output?  What if there's a schedule with multiple users -- same deal?  Or should they show up multiple times so that all the combinations are represented?

Comment: @Samwise By untouched I mean we keep the elements as it is in all the three lists....suppose if Chris has one more schedule named "abcd" and has corresponding value in list a [0,0,0,0] , so output will have that extra Chris in users  list and "abcd" in schedules list and [0,0,0,0] in list a. Please note all three list length will always be same.

Comment: Are the lists in `a` always equally long?

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a dictionary using pairs of `user` and `schedule` as keys so you can merge all the `a` values; then destructure that dictionary into the three new lists.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a = [[24, 24, 24, 24], [24, 24, 24, 24], [24, 24, 24, 24], [7, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [17, 7, 0, 0], [6, 1, 0, 0], [0, 17, 7, 0], [0, 6, 1, 0], [0, 0, 17, 0], [0, 0, 6, 1], [0, 0, 2, 5], [0, 0, 0, 6], [0, 0, 0, 4]]
users = ['Khod OR', 'Zader', 'Kamel Tor', 'Dave', 'Samir Fein', 'Chris', 'Samir Fein', 'Dave', 'Samir Fein', 'Chris', 'Samir Fein', 'Chris', 'Samir Fein', 'Dave']
schedules = ['ItSupport', 'NetworkOps', 'InfraDevOps', 'DBOps', 'SecOps', 'DBOps', 'SecOps', 'DBOps', 'SecOps', 'DBOps', 'SecOps', 'DBOps', 'SecOps', 'DBOps']

d = {}
for user, schedule, nums in zip(users, schedules, a):
    d[(user, schedule)] = [
        sum(z) for z in zip_longest(
            d.get((user, schedule), ()), nums, fillvalue=0
        )
    ]

users, schedules, a = zip(*((u, s, n) for (u, s), n in d.items()))

print(a)
print(users)
print(schedules)
# ([24, 24, 24, 24], [24, 24, 24, 24], [24, 24, 24, 24], [7, 17, 7, 4], [7, 7, 7, 7], [17, 7, 19, 5])
# ('Khod OR', 'Zader', 'Kamel Tor', 'Dave', 'Samir Fein', 'Chris')
# ('ItSupport', 'NetworkOps', 'InfraDevOps', 'DBOps', 'SecOps', 'DBOps')
```